# Synchronize Contacts on iPhone and iPad

Tags: data-synchronization, contacts, exchange

My iPhone and iPad both are connected on to the same exchange server.

Recently I cleaned up the contacts on my iPad.

On both devices I see revisions but most of the contacts deleted on my iPad are still in the contact list from the iPhone.

How is it possible the number of contacts on both devices differ?

Answer (score 1):

Each device has a local store of contacts. To synchronize things on each device - you can turn off Exchange sync and then see all the contacts that remain are local.

When you re-enable exchange sync - copy them one by one or choose to sync them all up to the cloud. Then repeat for each other device.

By setting the default place to store new contacts - you can avoid storing contacts locally or you can set time to clean up periodically if you don't remember to choose where to store each contact as you add them to the device.

Comment: When I switched of contacts under exchange , got the request to delete the contacts from the IPhone . Which I did. When I checked there were indeed none left. When I switched contacts on again , same number were visible as before on the Iphone.

Comment: @JvO Then you should be able to use Exchange online to count the contacts - and do the same on iOS - there's usually a mail setting to only download X thousand items or X days of content - but contacts should sync in entirety for how ever long it takes to get the sync complete. What is your count on iOS?